# Cannot import discord.py eventough its installed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

here is the terminal for the file that shows it is installed:

```
C:\Users\alex\Documents\alex\codism\python\Pycharm\BotsOn>pip install discord.py
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from discord.py) (3.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (2.10)
```

and when I:

```
import discord

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\Documents\alex\codism\python\Pycharm\BotsOn\SweepeyTesting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

Comment: check if you are working on same python environment  where discord.py is installed or not

Answer (score 1):

you are importing discord in your code and installed discord.py .

```
pip install discord
```

Install discord then import it.